# Trying to use speechSynthesis API in iOS webview app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, speech-synthesis

So I am trying to create an app that can do TTS.

I am using the speechSynthesis API inside of a webview app (React frontend, compiled with Cordova, though I am open to switching to React Native)

I've got a fairly standard implementation, which works on every browser, including Safari - sound even works in the iOS simulator via Xcode. However when I try to run it on my device, no sound works, even though the rest of the code I have associated with the speechAPI (mostly text highlighting) works as expected.

```
        function speechAPI(text, chardivs, speed, volume, version) {
            if (speechSynthesis.paused) {
                speechSynthesis.resume();
                return;
            }
            let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            let voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            msg.voiceURI = 'native';
            msg.volume = volume; // 0 to 1
            msg.rate = speed; // 0.1 to 10
            msg.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
            msg.text = text;
            msg.lang = 'zh-CN';
            msg.voice = voices[63];
...
```

I am not seeing any errors or anything like that. Is there some setting I am missing to make this API work via iOS? My device is on iOS 11, if that gives any useful information.

Comment: Probably not it, but try adding the Cordova media plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media (This plugin provides the ability to record and play back audio files on a device)

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not wrong, I understand that you're having trouble getting the iOS device to actually speak, on calling the SpeechSynthesis.speak() method.

I'm not entirely sure about the WebView, but Safari(which the WebView is probably based on) requires SpeechSynthesis.speak() to be triggered on a user action atleast once.
For example.

```
//This is the button a user has to click. after this event has been triggered,
//the speechSynthesis.speak() can be used autonomously as well.
document.getElementById('enable_voice_output').addEventListener('click', primeSpeak);
var speechPrimed = false;
function primeSpeak(){
  if(speechPrimed === false){
    var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Speech is enabled");
    speechSynthesis.speak(u);
    speechPrimed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. We can set the volume to be 0 so that the user won't notice it.